# Extracting Single from huge Archive using Perl

Tags: perl, extract, archive, tar

I'm trying a single from a large ".tgz" file. I'm using [Archive::Tar::Streamed](https://metacpan.org/module/Archive%3a%3aTar%3a%3aStreamed) module.

Here is the sample code.

```
my $tar2 = Archive::Tar::Streamed->new($filename);
$fil = $tar2->next;
while($fil) {
   $_ = $fil->name;
   if(m/abc\.txt/g) {
      $fil->extract($outpath);
      $fil = $tar2->next;
   }
}
```

But the iterator is not working. It is looping the first file in the archive not moving to the next file.
Can someone tell me what mistake i've done here???

Comment: Maybe you can use `Archive::Tar`, which is in the core and also has some kind of streaming support, see: https://metacpan.org/module/Archive::Tar#Archive::Tar-iter-filename-compressed-opt-val

Comment: i cannot use Archive::Tar because my tgz file size is more than 8GB. i ll ve memory problem.

Comment: Have you checked the link? It says "Returns an iterator function that reads the tar file without loading it all in memory." Don't know if it's true, but it's probably worth a try...

Comment: @SlavenRezic.. yes u re right.. wat i mean is tht the iterator is not working in my case..

Comment: "Not working" is an invalid problem description. What's the exact problem?

Comment: here it is.. when i use iterator, it is not moving the focus to the next file in the archive.. rather iterator always stays at the first file...

Comment: Can you show the source code for your attempt using Archive::Tar? (As an addition to your original post)

Answer (score 6):

You put the call to `next` inside your `if`, so it's only executed if you extracted the file.  There's nothing that modifies `$fil` inside the loop if the file is not extracted.

You can simplify your code quite a bit by just calling the iterator in the condition of the while loop.  Also, you can use the [`=~` binding operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Binding-Operators) instead of storing the name in `$_`.  And you *do not* want the `/g` regex modifier here.  In scalar context, you use `/g` to loop through multiple matches in a string.  Here, all you want is to know whether the string contains a match.

```
my $tar2 = Archive::Tar::Streamed->new($filename);
while(my $fil = $tar2->next) {
   if($fil->name =~ m/abc\.txt/) {
      $fil->extract($outpath);
   }
}
```

Comment: my tgz file has the following structure
folder1
--folder2
----folder3
-----file1
-----file2
-----file3

so when i run ur code, i m getting the output as,
folder1/folder2/folder3/file1
folder1/folder2/folder3/file1

Comment: The output path is controlled by `$outpath`.  You don't show where that came from.

Comment: forget about tht $outpath.. even if i print the name of the file in that place, it is printing the first file in the ttgx file again and again... iterator is not moving to the next file.. pls help

Comment: is that Archive::Tar::Streamed doesn't work for recursive folders inside archives????

Comment: It's possible you found a bug in Archive::Tar::Streamed.  The code I show shouldn't be stuck on the same file over and over.

Comment: have you tried this module?? do you have any working examples?? i could see no examples over the net.